# How to use sentry-cli for self hosted Sentry

Tags: sentry

I am trying to use command:

```
sentry-cli sourcemaps explain $EVENT --org $ORG --project $PROJECT_NAME
```

but response is

```
error: API request failed
  caused by: sentry reported an error: Invalid token (http status: 401)
```

My token is of course right in `.sentryclirc`.
With adding option `--log-level=debug` I noticed, that `sentry-cli` is trying to use `Host: sentry.io`, what is wrong.

So I tried to add parameter `--url $URL` to have

```
sentry-cli sourcemaps explain $EVENT --url $URL --org $ORG --project $PROJECT_NAME
```

but response is:

```
error: Found argument '--url' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

        If you tried to supply `--url` as a value rather than a flag, use `-- --url`
```

How can I use `sentry-cli sourcemaps explain` command for self hosted sentry then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right command is

```
sentry-cli --url $URL sourcemaps explain $EVENT  --org $ORG --project $PROJECT_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to provide the URL in `.sentryclirc` file:

```
[defaults]
url=your-custom-sentry-url
```