# ReactJs sentry error on deployment. API request failed

Tags: reactjs, sentry

When I run `yarn build`, everything completed but at the end I see the message:

> error: API request failed
> sentry reported an error: One or more projects are invalid (http status: 400)

Does anyone know how to solve that error?

Answer (score 3):

The error message you’re seeing indicates that the Sentry server has rejected your API request because it considers one or more of your projects to be invalid. This could be due to a variety of reasons, such as incorrect project settings or an invalid API token.

The error could be related to one of the following points

1. Check your project settings in Sentry: Make sure that the project names you’re using in your build process match exactly with the ones on the Sentry server.
2. Verify your API token: The API token is used to authenticate your requests to the Sentry server. If it’s invalid or expired, you’ll need to generate a new one. You can do this from your account settings on the Sentry website.
3. Check your sentry.properties file: This file contains the configuration for Sentry in your project. Make sure that the defaults.url, defaults.org, defaults.project, and auth.token fields are correctly set.
4. Update Sentry CLI: If you’re using an outdated version of Sentry CLI, updating it to the latest version might resolve the issue.

Also feel free to check the following links

https://forum.sentry.io/t/sentry-cli-invalid-token-api-request-failed/9097

https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/issues/1846

[How to use sentry-cli for self hosted Sentry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74822032/how-to-use-sentry-cli-for-self-hosted-sentry)

Comment: Thank you!
In my case, #3 worked: I changed a project name but forgot that this project is the default one and it needs to be changed in sentry.properties for both platforms as well.